# Python, syntax error using "if, elif"

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm new to Python and while trying to write a scrip that will keep asking questions about the user until the scrip gets FALSE,

I decided to check the scrip,of course it gave me an syntax error that told me the mistake was on the fifth lane, `a.

Now on that lane I tried to change the old value of a to a new value.
sadly, I can't understand the mistake that I made, can some one please check it and explain me what went wrong ?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello, I'm wilfred and I'm an Artificial Intelligence\n"

a=str(raw_input("Do you want to be my friend? \n"))

if a=="yes":
a=str(raw_input("Yey ! my first friend,what is your name?\n"))               
    if a==str :
        print "Nice name man!"
    elif a==int :
        print "bye!"
elif a=="no":
    print "Well, nice to meet you anway, good bye now \n"
```

Comment: You need to indent the statement immediately after the `if`, i.e. your 5th line. Basically it should be the beginning of a block i.e. with an indented statement.

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Comment: A common approach to getting the script to keep asking questions is to have a "while 1:" block, which will keep going around and around until some if statement breaks out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to indent the line. Your code should work fine. Keep learning python. It's awesome!!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello, I'm wilfred and I'm an Artificial Intelligence\n"

a=str(raw_input("Do you want to be my friend? \n"))

if a=="yes":
    a=str(raw_input("Yey ! my first friend,what is your name?\n"))               
    if a==str :
        print "Nice name man!"
    elif a==int :
        print "bye!"
elif a=="no":
    print "Well, nice to meet you anway, good bye now \n"
```

To further help with the test cases, I changed your string and int tests for you. "==" test is for value btw.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello, I'm wilfred and I'm an Artificial Intelligence\n"

a=str(raw_input("Do you want to be my friend? \n"))

if a=="yes":
    a=str(raw_input("Yey ! my first friend,what is your name?\n"))
    if a.isalpha() :
        print "Nice name man!"
    elif a.isdigit() :
        print "bye!"
elif a=="no":
    print "Well, nice to meet you anway, good bye now \n"
```

Comment: Thank you mate :D that helps me a lot !

Comment: No problem at all. Have fun learning :)

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
a=str(raw_input("Yey ! my first friend,what is your name?\n")
```

- Indent this line so it is inside the 'if' statement
- Add a ')' at the end of this line

Comment: How do I indent that is inside 'if' statement ?

Answer (score -2):

A general structure for this kind of repeating loop is

```
while True:
    a=str(raw_input(...)) 
    if a=="whatever": break
    # other responses to a
```

Comment: Though `while 1` works (since `1` is "truthy"), a more explicit version is `while True`. And while it's a reasonable suggestion, it's not really an answer to the question posed.

Comment: The OP's first sentence explains what's he's trying to do, so I was pre-empting the question a bit.

Comment: Also, while 1 is actually faster than while True, so is accepted practice. It generally doesn't matter though

Comment: I think it's going to keep asking questions deeper and deeper into the nested blocks of `if`/`elif`, not by repeating the same question over and over (which can be useful in other situations, like when you're rejecting invalid inputs).

Comment: I got a little bit confused, I'm not trying to ask the same question again and again, I'm trying to keep asking questions one by one, I need loop for that ?

Comment: "Also, while 1 is actually faster than while True, so is accepted practice."  Do you have something to illustrate that this is true?  I've never heard this, and I would disagree that within the Python community it is accepted practice.

Comment: "`while 1:`" is not faster than "`while True:`" it's **precisely** identical ... If you disassemble the bytecode, you get the exact same output (CPython optimises constant expressions in `while` loops).

Comment: @cyphar in Python 3, they are identical; in Python 2, they are a little different (`True` wasn't a keyword, so it needs to LOAD_GLOBAL). But even so, there's no way that difference is big enough to be important to fairly much anyone.

Comment: That's interesting. I read something about while 1 vs while True years ago, and developed the habit. Seems it was unnecessary!

Comment: Oh wow. Modifying `True` inside a `while True:` loop causes a binding error because of Python scoping. I didn't know that...

Comment: @lvc Yeah, I forgot about the whole thing where you could modify `True` in Python 2. Good times.